# Google Chrome mobile browser rendered the website only in download version after updated iOS to 16.1

Tags: ios, google-chrome

Chrome mobile browser for iOS and after updated iOS to 16.1 version rendered one of my website as a download. Anyone had the same problem? Earlier I've never seen that for the years. That problem is occasional but some of traffic is lost.

The url looks like this (on the left side see the download icon): [image: url's input in google chrome with download icon]

The rest part of the website is rendered only as a text and photo.

Others mobile browsers checked and I didn't see that problem. The same for Android but in this case  my website is the right rendered for all browsers.

Could you tell me where I should look for the reason of that problem?

Comment: Look in the html header. If you are using some external software this may lead to confusing the browser especially if some header tag are chrome specific. But without seeing any of the html code it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.